# how to implement onTouch listener?

Tags: android, touch-event

I want to add to my application a listener which allows a function of the position of the key on the screen displays the address and a message. I used the function below to get the position but I do not know, where to call the function and how.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    Log.d("Screen", String.valueOf(x));
    Log.d("Screen", String.valueOf(y));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is really hard to tell what you are actually asking. Can you elaborate some more and maybe try to re-word your question?

Comment: I would like to print the (x,y) position of my touch.  i am trying to creat a launcher and in some position, if we touch the screen we will have poopup

Comment: print it where? it seems like you are already printing it to the Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  like below

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        Log.d("Screen", String.valueOf(x));
        Log.d("Screen", String.valueOf(y));
        return true;
   } 
);
```

Comment: how to call the method, and where.

Comment: ok look at edited answer

Comment: i tired it but there is a problem the log is

Comment: I edited answer, change MotionEvent name from Arg1 to event